# Nothing is displayed on the screen after form submission

Tags: php, arrays

I've looked and tried many of the solutions here and on other sites but I am still befuddled (still doing the PHP school thing, but something is eluding me).

I have a page that a user can select multiple check boxes and it builds the data:

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$filename = "../files/Awards_$username.txt";
$award = $_POST['awardrec'];
file_put_contents($filename, print_r($award, true), FILE_APPEND)
?>
```

Simple enough. It writes the data as:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Value1
    [1] => Value2
    [2] => Value3
    [3] => Value4
    [4] => Value5
    [5] => Value6
)
```

But nothing I seem to do results in anything being displayed. No error messages; nothing, just a white page.

Ultimately it's just a page that will read the data and display a graphic associated with the value.

Where would a good article on this type of operation be?

Comment: Show us the code that doesn't work

Comment: You do not output anything in this code, thus resulting in a blank page...

Comment: You need a semicolon after `file_put_contents($filename, print_r($award, true), FILE_APPEND)`.

Comment: [`var_dump()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php), [`print_r()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php), [`echo ''`](http://us2.php.net/echo)?

Comment: the code referenced in my post is that, that builds the data file, of course it doesn't display anything, I do see where my lapse in conveying the problem.. I want to build another page to display that data/ pull up a graphic associated with the values. The codes that I tried had not worked... @Sharanya Dutta thank you for that, ironically [and mysteriously] the code works with or without it.. lol i tried it both ways once you pointed that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve but this should help at least a bit hopefully in the right direction :

```
<?php
//  For test
//  $_POST['username'] = 'some_username';
//  $_POST['awardrec'] = array( 'award_one' ,'award_two' );

    if( ! isset( $_POST['username'] ) )
    {
        echo 'username is not set';
        exit;
    }

    $username = trim( $_POST['username'] );

    if( $username == '' )
    {
        echo 'username is empty';
        exit;
    }

    $filename = "../files/Awards_$username.txt";

    if( ! isset( $_POST['awardrec'] ) )
    {
        echo 'awardrec is not set';
        exit;
    }

    $award = $_POST['awardrec'];

//  Save the contents to file
    file_put_contents( $filename ,print_r( $award ,true ) ,FILE_APPEND );

//  Display contents
    echo 'Username : ' ,$username ,'<br>';

    echo 'Awards :' ,'<br>';

    foreach( $award as $value )
    {
        echo $value .'<br>';
    }
```

Comment: Many thanks! I will try it out, I've honestly only dived into PHP in the last few months... the basics are awesome, Its almost as easy as old windows batch scripting..

Comment: the code that i referenced before would show everything, Eventually the data that is written by server batch scripts will be worked to replace old txt display info. this particular need was for the pages I wrote for our gaming [of all things], I want to have a page that will display the medals won by each user and I think your code is exactly what was needed! I started to track in game money. I seem to be addding tons more of utilities.

Comment: Ok I've referenced the /questions/5393085/display-an-array-in-a-readable-format/5393128#5393128 page on reading the data that is written since it is the same type as my page. And I've tried the accepted solution and several of the others. but I either get everything as a return or it is at least in a column including the uneeded info..
foreach($data[0] as $child) {echo $child . "\n";}
I also tried the
"function pr($data){print "<pre>";print_r($data);print "</pre>";} they were the only 2 that worked. the resulting page is at
   2comm.hopto.org/prod/wothonR.php?USNM=USERNAME

Comment: You probably would need to show how your data is now and how you would want to show it as . It will also be useful if you can show the code you are using currently . You can update your question with the above info . Before doing that you can have a look at [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function . I am thinking you would just need to explode each of your data line by `:` . Try it and see .